# rpy2 installation overwrites R_HOME and breaks RStudio

Tags: linux, python, path, rstudio

I recently installed rpy2 via pip: `$ pip install rpy2`, to use R from inside python. This worked and I can use it in python, however it seems to have overwritten all my R environment variables, and now I can't use RStudio anymore. It just leaves my with a chrome startscreen, telling me:

> This site can’t be reached
>   127.0.0.1 refused to connect. Try:
>
> Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

When I start RStudio via terminal I get `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'notifyRCrashed' of undefined"`

When I run `rstudio --run-diagnostics` it returns

```
Using R script: /home/nhoeche/anaconda3/bin/R

Attempting to launch R session...
  R_HOME=/home/nhoeche/anaconda3/lib/R
  R_DOC_DIR=/home/nhoeche/anaconda3/lib/R/doc
  R_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/nhoeche/anaconda3/lib/R/include
  R_SHARE_DIR=/home/nhoeche/anaconda3/lib/R/share
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/nhoeche/anaconda3/lib/R/lib:
  PATH=/home/nhoeche/anaconda3/bin:/home/nhoeche/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/nhoeche/.local/bin:/home/nhoeche/bin
  HOME=/home/nhoeche

R session launched, attempting to connect on port 9681...
/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rsession: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/nhoeche/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/../../libicuuc.so.58)
/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rsession: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/nhoeche/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/../../libicuuc.so.58)
/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rsession: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/nhoeche/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/../../libicui18n.so.58)
/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rsession: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/nhoeche/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/../../libicui18n.so.58)

Connected to R session, attempting to initialize...
```

The path `/home/nhoeche/anaconda3/bin/R` definitely refers to my python R installation, not my "normal" one. How can I retrieve where my normal installation is and reset all the paths?

I already tried reinstalling R and RStudio, and I tried deleting / moving `.rstudio-desktop`, `RData` and so on....

My operating system is CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem originated from the anaconda path preceeding my "normal" path. `$ echo $PATH` gave me

```
/home/nhoeche/anaconda3/bin:/home/nhoeche/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/nhoeche/.local/bin:/home/nhoeche/bin
```

`rpy2` installed `r-base` in anaconda which is why my system took the python-R installation as default. This is why removing `rpy2` or `rstudio or R did nothing, because`r-base` was still there in anaconda.

I uninstalled `rpy2` as well as `r-base` in anaconda to resolve this. I also specified `export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/bin/R` in `.profile` just to be sure. It works fine again now.

I read that if you install `rpy2` via `pip` rather than via `conda`, it is possible to have it point to your "default" r installation, rather than installing it again inside anaconda.

Comment: i don't have rpy2 and r-base in my conda-list. Still facing the issue.
echo $PATH gaves me following OP

/home/susaj/anaconda3/condabin:/home/susaj/bin:/home/susaj/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin